# How to type hint overloaded method with overlapping arguments using Mypy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

I'm facing a problem referenced [in Mypy documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#type-checking-the-variants) but with no provided workaround:

```py
from typing import overload, Union

@overload
def unsafe_func(x: int) -> int: ...

@overload
def unsafe_func(x: object) -> str: ...

def unsafe_func(x: object) -> Union[int, str]:
    if isinstance(x, int):
        return 42
    else:
        return "some string"
```

This generates the following error ([see Mypy playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=6d026f788e61243061e750eb01059d72)):

```
main.py:4: error: Overloaded function signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I do understand the reason (`int` is also an `object` so `unsafe_func(42)` can't be resolved unambiguously), but I don't know how to fix it.

How to type hint the function so that express that `int -> int` and `any other object -> str`?

---

The real use case is to create a decorator with optional argument:

```py
from inspect import isclass

def catcher(function_or_exception):
    # Case when decorator is used with argument
    # 'function_or_exception' is of type 'Exception'
    if isclass(function_or_exception) and issubclass(function_or_exception, BaseException):
        def decorator(decorated):
            def decorate():
                try:
                    decorated()
                except function_or_exception:
                    print("An error occurred")
            return decorate
        return decorator

    # Case when decorator is used without arguments.
    # 'function_or_exception' is of type 'Callable'
    else:
        def decorate():
            try:
                function_or_exception()
            except Exception:
                print("An error occurred")
        return decorate

@catcher
def my_func_1():
    "1" + 1

@catcher(ZeroDivisionError)
def my_func_2():
    1 / 0


my_func_1()
my_func_2()
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you even want this? The two functions are clearly different functions (different input type ***and*** different output type). Why do they have the same name? Is there a real use case for this?

Comment: @wovano I implemented only one function for convenience. To be more precise, the exact function I'm trying to type hint is [this one](https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/logger.html#loguru._logger.Logger.catch) (see examples).

Comment: @wovano I added an simplified implementation of the real use case although it's not necessarily very straightforward.  ;)

Comment: What you're showing IS a workaround, indeed.  It is "undefined behaviour", but in fact `mypy` tries overloaded definitions in source order, and same does Pyright, AFAIC. You can add ignore comment to overload definition to silence that error and verify that `reveal_type(unsafe_func(1))` is `builtins.int` and `reveal_type(unsafe_func([]))` is `builtins.str`.

Comment: @SUTerliakov Damn, it's as simple as adding a `#type: ignore` comment... Thanks for the hint! Would you like to convert your comment into an answer so I can close my question (otherwise I will make a community answer)?

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to suggest a slightly different implementation that doesn't cause typing issues with `@overload`. It uses the common pattern for decorators that can be used with or without parentheses. The difference is that the exception class would have to be passed as a *keyword* argument.

Here is a full working example (Python `3.10+` due to the use of [`ParamSpec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec)):

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from functools import wraps
from typing import ParamSpec, TypeVar, overload


P = ParamSpec("P")
T = TypeVar("T")


@overload
def catcher(func: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T | None]:
    ...


@overload
def catcher(
    *,
    exc: type[BaseException] = Exception,
) -> Callable[[Callable[P, T]], Callable[P, T | None]]:
    ...


def catcher(
    func: Callable[P, T] | None = None,
    *,
    exc: type[BaseException] = Exception,
) -> Callable[P, T | None] | Callable[[Callable[P, T]], Callable[P, T | None]]:
    def decorator(function: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T | None]:
        @wraps(function)
        def inner_wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T | None:
            try:
                return function(*args, **kwargs)
            except exc as e:
                print(f"{e.__class__.__name__} occurred")
                return None
        return inner_wrapper
    return decorator if func is None else decorator(func)


@catcher
def my_func_1() -> None:
    raise TypeError


@catcher(exc=ZeroDivisionError)
def my_func_2() -> float:
    return 1 / 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_func_1()
    x = my_func_2()
```

Output:

```
TypeError occurred
ZeroDivisionError occurred
```

No issues with `mypy --strict`.

While using the decorator is only slightly more verbose, it is arguably a bit "safer" with regard to the types involved. The implementation itself on the other hand is *less* verbose because you only define the inner functions/wrappers *once*.

I tried a few things, but was unable to safely construct the desired signature using the exception class as a positional argument.

Comment: Python3.8 with mypy `error: Module "typing" has no attribute "ParamSpec"; maybe "_ParamSpec"`, and then `error: Module "typing" does not explicitly export attribute "_ParamSpec"`

Comment: @ryanjdillon Well, yes, [`ParamSpec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec) is new in `3.10`. That is why I explicitly mentioned the version in my answer.

Comment: Just a breadcrumb for others, as ParamSpec's public api being only available in `3.10` was *not* explicitly mentioned.

Comment: @ryanjdillon I wrote the minimum requirements for my code literally right on top of it, but fine, to indicate why _exactly_ the requirement is `3.10` I edited the post.

Comment: You wrote that you had run your code with python `3.10`, not that `3.10` was a minimum requirement. I tried it with `3.8`, and didn't work, hence my comment. Far more helpful what you have there now. Thanks :)